# Can coauthors split the article publishing charge?

Tags: publications, fees

Is the article processing charge paid only by the corresponding author or can it be split among all coauthors, with separate bills and receipts?

Comment: There are some prior questions (IMO not duplicates) relating to splitting fees, for example [Splitting publication fees among coauthors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10695/17254), [When authors from multiple universities contribute to an article, who pays for open-access fees?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/192274/17254)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the publisher. For example, the IEEE does allow it:
https://supportcenter.ieee.org/app/answers/detail/a_id/1385/kw/payment/related/1

Comment: I don't know that any publisher *disallows* it.  IEEE merely provides a convenient mechanism to do it.

Comment: Even if a publisher does not disallow it, it may still not provide separate bills and receipts, as required for accounting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (at least in my experience).  I’ve done this in two ways.

1. The publisher (*v.g* the American Physical Society) or its representative has a payment website where partial payments can be done.  The software keeps track of the amounts of various institutions until the full amount is reached.  The invoice includes the names of the various parties and the amounts they paid.
2. One person or grant pays the entire fee and my grant reimburses this person or grant through normal institution-to-institution invoicing or bank transfer.

In all instances I’m familiar with, publishers have recognized that there may be more than one person paying the APC so option 1 is now the most common (at least with larger publisher in physics).

Comment: thanks for your input. the question asked for separate bills and receipts. this may be required for acccounting purposes.

Comment: @FelipeG.Nievinski sorry I do not understand your reply.  How is an itemized bill stating that you paid xxx not enough?  How is an invoice (with supporting documentation) from your collaborator for APC charge not enough?  Precisely because of accounting rules, all publishers I know will produce separate invoices or itemized invoices.

Comment: your option 1, invoicing directly from the publisher, is fine. it's option 2 that I find problematic. in my experience, universities would not accept an invoice not from the publisher.

Comment: @FelipeG.Nievinski well that’s not my experience.  Granted I have not done option 2 in a while but I *have* done it in the past, paperwork and all.

Comment: ok, I tried to undo my downvote, but it says "You last voted on this answer 4 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Comment: @FelipeG.Nievinski not a big deal…if you are insistent I can make a spurious edit but it’s really not that big of a deal.  My life does not depend on 2 rep points.